# como acualizar un string de un array en angular

Tags: angular

estoy haciendo un simple crud en Angular  5.2, tengo un problema en el metodo updateItem al intentar actualizar un valor del array, se actualizan todos los que tienen el mismo nombre

//HTML

```
   <form> 
     <div class="form-group">
      <h1 class="text-center text-primary">Todo App</h1> 
      <div class="input-group-prepend"> 
        <input  type="text" #todo class="form-control" placeholder="Add Todo" 
      name="todo"  ngModel>
        <span class="input-group-text" (click)="addTodo(todo.value) "><i 
         class="material-icons">add</i></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="data">  
                    <ul class="list-instyled">         
                        <li *ngFor="let todo of todoArray">{{todo}} 
                          <i (click)="deleteItem(todo)" class="material- 
            icons">delete</i>
                          <i (click)="updateItem(todo)" class="material- 
            icons">update</i></li>
                          </ul>  </div>
                  </div>
                 </form>
```

//JS

```
 export class AppComponent { 
  todoArray: string[] = [];
   addTodo(value:any){
    this.todoArray.push(value) 
       console.log(this.todoArray) 
       } 
    deleteItem(todo:any){ 
          for(let i=0 ;i<= this.todoArray.length ;i++)
        {  
            if(todo== this.todoArray[i])
            { 
                  this.todoArray.splice(i,1)
            } 
        }
       }
       updateItem(todo:string){ 

        for(let i=0 ;i<= this.todoArray.length ;i++)
      {  
          if(todo== this.todoArray[i])
          { 
            this.todoArray.splice(i,1, "Nuevo nombre")
            
          } 
      }
     }
```

//he añadido una imagen al momento de dar click al icono de actualizar se actualizan todos al nombre que ingrese, en vez de acutalizar uno solo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El splice lo que hace es insertar el nuevo valor y correr el resto de elementos una posición a la derecha. Si lo que quieres es editar el elemento, en esa posición en específico, puede cambiarlo directamente con el índice, por ejemplo:

```
for(let i=0 ;i<= this.todoArray.length ;i++) {  
  if(todo== this.todoArray[i]) { 
     this.todoArray[i] = "Nuevo nombre";
  } 
}
```

Eso cambiaría cada elemento que cumpla con el valor recibido como parametro, si quieres que solo cambie el primer elemento encontrado, entonces puedes usar un break para detener el for:

```
for(let i=0 ;i<= this.todoArray.length ;i++) {  
  if(todo== this.todoArray[i]) { 
     this.todoArray[i] = "Nuevo nombre";
     break;
  } 
}
```